# Unable to build msql virtual machine from terraform, using azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine. Errorcode: CRPNotAllowedOperation

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-extension

I'm running azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine to build a SQL Server virtual machine from a custom imag. (Image configured with SQL Server 2016 prepare image).

This is the code that I am running:

```
  resource "azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine" "mssql_vm" {
  provider            = azurerm.spoke-subscription
  virtual_machine_id  = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.sql_server.id
  sql_license_type                 = "PAYG"
  sql_connectivity_port            = "49535"
  sql_connectivity_update_username = var.sql_login
  sql_connectivity_update_password = var.sql_password
  sql_instance {
    collation = "Latin1_General_CI_AS"
  }
  assessment {
    enabled = true
    run_immediately = true
  }
  storage_configuration {
  disk_type             = "${var.disk_type}"
  storage_workload_type = "OLTP"
    data_settings {
      default_file_path = "F:\\DATA"
      luns              = [1]
    }
    log_settings {
      default_file_path = "G:\\LOGS"
      luns              = [2]                 
    }
    temp_db_settings {
      default_file_path = "K:\\TEMPDB"
      luns              = [3]                
    }
   }
   lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      tags,
     #assessment[0].schedule
    ]
  }
   tags = {
      "application owner" = var.application_owner_tag
      "environment"       = var.environment_tag
      "department"        = var.department_tag
      "technicalcontact"  = var.technicalcontact_tag
      "application"       = var.application_tag
      "service"           = "SQL server"
    }
 }
```

I get this error:

> performing CreateOrUpdate: sqlvirtualmachines.SqlVirtualMachinesClient#CreateOrUpdate: Failure sending request: StatusCode=0 --
> Original Error: Code="CRPNotAllowedOperation" Message="Operation cannot be completed due to the following error: VM Extension with publisher 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management' and type 'SqlIaaSAgent' does not support setting enableAutomaticUpgrade property to true on this subscription.

Steps I've taken to try and resolve:

1. Re-register SQL Server virtual machines to the Azure subscription
2. Turned off automatic upgrade on azurerm_windows_virtual_machine

Answer (score 0):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment:***

**Code:**

```
resource "azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine" "example" {
  virtual_machine_id               = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.example.id
  sql_license_type                 = "PAYG"
  r_services_enabled               = true
  sql_connectivity_port            = 1433
  sql_connectivity_type            = "PRIVATE"
  sql_connectivity_update_password = "xxx"
  sql_connectivity_update_username = "sqllogin"

  auto_patching {
    day_of_week                            = "Sunday"
    maintenance_window_duration_in_minutes = 60
    maintenance_window_starting_hour       = 2
  }
  
}


resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "example" {
  name                = "kavexample-network"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "example" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.example.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "example" {
  name                = "kavya-example-nic"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.example.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                = "kavyaexamplemc"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  size                = "Standard_F2"
  admin_username      = "xxx"
  admin_password      = "xx"
  enable_automatic_updates   = true
  patch_mode = "Manual"
  hotpatching_enabled = true
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.example.id,
  ]

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    offer     = "WindowsServer"
    sku       = "2016-Datacenter"
    version   = "latest"
  }
}
```

**Received same error:**

```
│ Error: waiting for creation of Sql Virtual Machine (Sql Virtual Machine Name "kavyaexamplemc" / Resource Group "v-sakavya-Mindtree"): Code="CRPNotAllowedOperation" Message="Operation cannot be completed due to the following error: VM Extension with publisher 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management' and type 'SqlIaaSAgent' does not support setting enableAutomaticUpgrade property to true on this subscription."
```

[image]

Even tried changing, but was still receving the same error again and again.

```
enable_automatic_updates   = false
      patch_mode = "Manual"
      hotpatching_enabled = false
```

Try deleting the vm resource completely and create a new one with changed settings .

Try using below code:

I tried setting    **`enable_automatic_upgrades = false`** , azurerm_virtual_machine has this property .Make use of that.
Also ,

**Code:**

```
resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "main" {
  name                = "kavyasarvnetwork"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "internal" {
  name                 = "internal"
  resource_group_name  = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.main.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.2.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "main" {
  name                = "kavyasarnic"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "testconfiguration1"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.internal.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "example" {
  name                  = "kavyasarvm"
  location              = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name   = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.main.id]
  vm_size               = "Standard_DS1_v2"
 
   storage_os_disk {
    name              = "kavyasar-OSDisk"
    caching           = "ReadOnly"
    create_option     = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = "Premium_LRS"
    os_type = "Windows"
  }

    storage_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftSQLServer"
    offer     = "SQL2017-WS2016"
    sku       = "SQLDEV"
    version   = "latest"
  }
  os_profile {
    computer_name  = "hostname"
    admin_username = "testadmin"
    admin_password = "Password1234!"
  }

  os_profile_windows_config {
    timezone                  = "Pacific Standard Time"
    provision_vm_agent        = true
    enable_automatic_upgrades = false
  }
  
  tags = {
    environment = "staging"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine" "example" {

  virtual_machine_id               = azurerm_virtual_machine.example.id
  sql_license_type                 = "PAYG"
  r_services_enabled               = true
  sql_connectivity_port            = 1433
  sql_connectivity_type            = "PRIVATE"
  sql_connectivity_update_password = "Password1234!"
  sql_connectivity_update_username = "sqllogin"
}
```

This seems to be the cause due to limitations:  [What is the SQL Server IaaS Agent extension? (Windows) - SQL Server on Azure VMs | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/sql-server-iaas-agent-extension-automate-management?view=azuresql&tabs=azure-powershell#limitations)

> The SQL IaaS Agent extension **only supports**:
>
> **SQL Server VMs deployed through the `Azure Resource Manager`. SQL Server
> VMs deployed through the classic model are not supported.**
>
> **SQL Server VMs deployed to the public or Azure Government cloud.
> Deployments to other private or government clouds are not supported.**

**Reference** : [azurerm_mssql_virtual_machine | Resources | hashicorp/azurerm | Terraform Registry](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/mssql_virtual_machine#auto_patching)

Comment: Hi, we're also receiving the same error. I tried with your code and setting `enable_automatic_upgrades = false`, but the same error still gets thrown

Comment: Check if VM is in running state and properly set .Check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/troubleshoot#verify-that-the-vm-agent-is-running-and-ready)

Comment: I am using azurerm_windows_virtual_machine, to deploy the initial VM. Therefore the enable_automatic_upgrades option is not there for me.

Comment: Hi, I'm thinking Azure might have fixed something on their end, as without any changes deploying VMs now works again for us.